# Converting to hex?

Tags: c#, hex

Whenever I try to convert '™' to hex string using

```
string.Format("{0:X}", (int)"™");
```

It returns 2122 which is weird because when I use online converters I get 99. Why?

Comment: What encoding are you comparing to for the online conversion?

Comment: Not sure, but I'm think it's Unicode since ™ is Unicode char ?

Comment: I show the unicode for the ™ as 0x2122 in the unicode converter I went to...

Comment: Here is the converter which I used : http://www.string-functions.com/string-hex.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

99 is the code for ™ in the Windows-1252 encoding, while 2122 is the code according to the Unicode standard.

Comment: Is it possible to convert it to Windows-1252 ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.convert%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

As explained by Cito, 99 is the code for ™ in the Windows-1252 encoding. You can get it as follows:

```
var result = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")
                     .GetBytes("™")
                     .Single()
                     .ToString("X");

// result == "99"
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that 2122 is the correct response. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTBxZ.png

99 is not correct: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ASCII+153

Answer (score 0):

The conversion is correct. According to [this site](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2122/index.htm) the unicode value of TM is 2122.